# How to cycle through record set and update table field values based on record set?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am importing similar tables into a MS Access database to combine them into a larger data set. The first row of most of the columns are date fields. During import when the first row becomes field names, some of these dates stay dates "January-2018" and some of them become numbers "44001". I am writing a code to reference any numbers that are store as the field names and turn them into date values (ex. 44001 to January-2018).

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim CurrentHead As String
Dim UpdateHead As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("PL_1")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TableUpdates")

rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF
For Each fld In tdf
If fld.Name = CurrentHead Then
fld.Name = UpdateHead
End If
rs.MoveNext
Loop

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing

MsgBox "Changed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome! Your code doesn't make sense. You open a recordset `rs`, but never use it inside your `Do While Not rs.EOF` loop. Variables `CurrentHead` and `UpdateHead` are defined, but never given values. You should close `rs` when you are done with it. Dynamically renaming fields on an existing table probably makes more work than it saves.

Comment: Thank you! Dynamically renaming fields is the best way to go given that the imported spreadsheets' fields come in randomly as either a date or a number so I'll need to get those renamed. I'm trying to open the recordset "TableUpdates" in order to run this list against the fields of the imported table to see if Access had changed the fields to numbers (I want dates), and if so to then change the number to a date. How would I do that?

Comment: Is the goal to produce uniform tables with consistent naming of all fields? Or do the tables vary in the number of columns and their names? What does `TableUpdates` contain? Is the data coming from Excel?

Comment: TableUpdates contains the date number that Excel sometimes converts dates into and the corresponding date spelled out as January-2019. TableUpdates is a table in the Access db that I'm trying to use as a basis for correcting the field names. The goal is to produce uniform tables with consistent naming fields (due to Access converting some of the column headers that are dates into numbers).

Comment: If you have control over the import, you could try fixing the column names on the Excel side. Or, you can think about importing into a temporary table in Access, and building a SQL INSERT statement in code that maps the temp values into the proper fields in the permanent table.

Comment: I don't have control over the Excel spreadsheets. And the spreadsheets' headings are randomly interpreted as either numbers or dates and so I would need a code that cleans up the field names after import. Could I just create a table of what the possible date numbers are and then search the field names to see if the field name has been converted from a date into its corresponding date number, and if this conversion has occurred to then change that field value into its corresponding date?

Comment: The probable reason why the headings get changed is that they are being stored in Excel as either dates or strings. The Excel dates get converted to numbers when imported to Access, but the strings come through OK. I would suggest importing to a temporary table, matching the imported field names to your permanent table, and making a SQL insert to move the data. You can then overwrite the temporary table on the next import.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I will give that a try. There are a dozen spreadsheets that I am importing and the headings come in randomly as either dates or strings. What would be the best way to account for this when building the SQL insert statement?

Comment: A simple example: 
Import table headings: "Jan-2019", 45600, "Mar-2019";  
Permanent table headings: "Jan-2019", "Feb-2019", "Mar-2019";  
SQL: INSERT INTO Permanent_Table ([Jan-2019], [Feb-2019], [Mar-2019]) SELECT [Jan-2019], [45600], [Mar-2019] FROM temp_table;  
You build the SQL by looping through temp_table in code and calculating the matching field in permanent_table.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. How do I build a loop that builds the SQL statement?

Comment: A better question might be - how do I loop through and calculate that matching field in the permanent table?

Comment: If the temp field name is numeric, `IsNumeric(tempName) = True`, you can get the permanent name using `Format(CDate(tempName), "mmmm-yyyy")`. As you loop through the temporary field names, you use the formatted value as the destination (permanent) name in your INSERT, and the temporary name as the source name.

Comment: As I'm writing the code our here it looks like this solution is more static than dynamic. Right now i'd like to import forecasts for 2019-2021, but in 6 months we might want to import forecasts for 2022. How did I code it in such that I can select a drop down on a form and select the time period I'd like to pull on import?

Comment: Once you get the current idea working, you can easily extend it. I would let the date range of the import columns determine which columns to insert. The permanent table would need more fields. Access tables hold up to 255 fields, which would give you 21 years of future monthly forecast columns. In much the same way as you generate INSERT statements, you can easily generate SQL SELECT statements to query whatever range of the permanent table you want to report on. The dropdown that selects the range can be just an arbitrary value list that holds the allowed ranges.

Comment: So there are two possible dates that come through. Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("PL_1")
Dim fld As DAO.Field

'Jan2019
Jan2019 = DLookup("TempHead1", "TableUpdates", "Permhead = '1/1/2019'")
For Each fld In rs1.Fields
    If fld.Name = Jan2019 Then DataCounter = (DataCounter + 1) Else DataCoutner = DateCounter
Next
Set fld = Nothing
If DataCounter > 0 Then GoTo NextFeb2019 Else GoTo ChangeJan2019

ChangeJan2019:
Jan2019 = DLookup("TempHead2", "TableUpdates", "Permhead = '1/1/2019'")

NextFeb2019:

Comment: This is the code I've started, but it only works for one month at a time. How would I get the code to automatically cycle through?

Comment: I created the table "TableUpdates" which includes the associated date (Column1) in the permanent table and the two possible dates (Column2 and 3) from the temporary table.

Comment: Please move the code in your comment to your answer so I can easily read it.